# How to update custom objects metadata in mavensmate

Tags: metadata, mavensmate

I added some fields to custom object on the org and wanted to update its metadata in my project in mavensmate.

I tried to click on this object and choose "Refresh from server", it doesnt work.
Then: mavensmate - project - edit project - customObjects - right click "Refresh from server", it shows the updating process, but metadata doesnt change at all.

How to do this in right way, guys?
Thanks

Comment: is this object not listed under CustomObjects in the package.xml?  package.xml should also have a <members>*</members> entry under CustomObject, to pull in all the new objects.    Additionally, what is the Field visibility set to on those fields?  If your profile is not set to see them, they won't pull in into the project.

Comment: ok, i added <members>*</members> to the package. that obj and fields are visible for me, double checked this! Ok, lets say my mavensmate with wrong adjustments. How to get metadata of object in xml?

Comment: Usually I will type metadata manually in package.xml then Refresh from Server.Have you try this?

Comment: Do you do this in MavensMate? I guess i tried this also, need to check again. Actually i got metadata via eclipse + force.com plugin, just created there new project and it pulled all data from my org.

Answer (score 1):

Fix this problem with:
Click right mouse on project (root folder) in MavensMate and choose Refresh from server, so it refreshed the whole project, after that everything started to work.